# Is this proof missing a "push-up" step? Every non-empty set of real number bounded from below has a greatest lower bound.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers

This is from [BBFSK](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D), Vol-I pages 142 and 143.  The reference to $\S{4.1}$ means for whole numbers $a_i\lt{g}$ and $g\gt{1}$

$$r_n=\sum _{i=0}^{n} a_i g^{-i}.$$

The expression in the sentence following (63) below should be $\left\vert r_m-r_n\right\vert <g^{-n_o}.$

The authors define $r_n$ as the greatest integral multiple of $g^{-n}$ where $g\gt{1}$ is an integer.  In order for this to make sense, it seems to require $0\le{r_n},$ and thus eq (64) $,r_n\le\lim{r}\le{r_n+g^{-n}}$ requires that $0\le\lim{r}$.  They conclude that $\lim{r}$ is the greatest lower bound of $M$.

In order for this proof to work, it seems we first need to "push up" all of $M$ so that $0$ is a lower bound of $M-s=\left\{x\backepsilon{x=m-s\land{m\in{M}}}\right\},$ and $s\le{0}$ is a lower bound of $M$.  Is this correct?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it only requires that $\lim r$ exists and is a real number.  If it does it is a lower bound and nothing larger is so it it the greatest lower bound. ... But what I don't understand is how were the real numbers defined and how do we know $\lim r$ exists. ... Does this text define the real numbers as all bounded limits converge or something?  ...I much more familiar with the idea that the real numbers have this property true by definition.

Comment: They use different definitions at different stages of their development and then prove the alternative definitions are mutually isomorphic thus making the proofs applicable to all definitions.  In this section they are using limits of "fundamental sequences", which are often called Cauchy sequences. $r$ is just the sequence of $r_n$ defined above.

Comment: Yeah, after I commented I read the description.  It's valid an fair.   ... I guess I'm not really understanding what you  are asking.... the prove seems to be that if the set is bounded below then we can make a cauchy sequence of rational lower bounds.  Being cauchy it converges to a real $r$ and that $r$ is the greatest lower bound.  Which is perfectly sound (to the extent I eyeballed it).... So maybe I don't really see what you are asking.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the numbers $r_n$ are all positive,  At least that's how they are defined in $\S 4.1$.  It's just a fancy way of writing decimal-point expressions.  Previously, in the proof for real numbers defined by infinite sums produced by taking $n\to\infty,$ they included a push-up step.  See page 132, top paragraph.  I don't see how they can avoid doing the same here.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton: I agree: so far as I can see, the $r_n$ are non-negative. (And the statement that $r_n$ is the greatest integer multiple of $g^{-n}$ that is still a lower bound of $M$ is wrong: it’s the sum that you displayed that’s still a lower bound of $M$.)

Comment: If you think about it, you will see that the sum is evenly divisible by $g^{-n}$.  That is, 5.27 is an integral multiple of $10^2.$

Comment: Meh! that should be $10^{-2}$